# find multiple values from comma separated fields

Tags: mysql

working for school project - principal will select in which course they will teach - staff will select which subject they will teach
if any subject is already select by another staff, then it should not be displayed for selection

I need teaching Subject for the staff teaching in same course

as per current scenario user id 2 teaching in 1,2,3,5
but other staff is also teaching in same course so in need that teaching subject ids which other staff is teaching so current staff won't able to select same subject

[image: course table]

[image: subject table]

[image: user table]

Comment: It's simple. Either revise your design so as to omit the requirement for comma delimited values, or don't bother with an RDBMS.

Comment: design suggestion please

Comment: See normalisation.